# Image in Android OpenGL ES

Tags: android, bitmap

I was wondering what is the data-structure of the `bitmap` we're getting as an output here:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.mypngimage);
```

Comment: You can use Bitmap.getPixels() to get the raw data as RGBA (4 bytes per pixel).

Comment: Actually I have an RGBA array and want to convert it to a bitmap. Hence I want to know the data structure of a bitmap!